# Flexbox not wrapping how intended

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm new to performing dev jobs entirely myself but have been exposed to a lot of it in work previously - I'm really loving it but I've got an issue with my items within a container re: wrapping the items via flexbox and wondering if someone out there could help?

I'm trying to set an order for the timeline on the attached for desktop to be:

1  2

3  4

5  6

and for mobile:

1

2

3

4

5

6

At the moment it's displaying in in a vertical direction only which is okay for mobile, though I want it to spill into and wrap over 2 columns.

I've looked on walkthroughs re: flex-wrap but nothing I try is working - I may be barking up the wrong tree.

Can anyone out there please help?

Thanks!

GC

```css
/* order timeline */

.timeline-order {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-flow: wrap row;
}

.row .timeline-1 {
    order: 1;
}

.row .timeline-2 {
    order: 2;
}

.row .timeline-3 {
    order: 3;
}

.row .timeline-4 {
    order: 4;
}

.row .timeline-5 {
    order: 5;
}

.row .timeline-6 {
    order: 6;
}

.timeline {
    padding: 60px 0
}

.timeline .section-headline {
    margin-bottom: 60px
}

.timeline-item {
    float: left;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #222;
    border-top: 6px solid #333;
    padding: 10%;
    margin: 15px 0
}

.timeline-item-image {
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    margin-bottom: 60px
}

.timeline time {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    opacity: .8
}

.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto
}

@media (min-width:576px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 540px
    }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 720px
    }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 960px
    }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1140px
    }
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff
}
```

```html
<section class="timeline">
        <div class="container timeline-order">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class='section-headline'>The Timeline</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-1">
                        <img src="/images/timeline/pioneer.jpg" width='240' alt="Pioneer 0" class="timeline-item-image">
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <time>17 August 1958</time>
                            <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-2">
                        <img src="/images/timeline/luna-1.jpg" width='240' alt="Luna E-1 No.1" class="timeline-item-image">
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <time>23 September 1958</time>
                            <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                                <br/> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-3">
                        <img src="/images/timeline/apollo-11.jpg" width='240' alt="Apollo 11" class="timeline-item-image">
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <time>16 July 1969</time>
                            <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-4">
                        <img src="/images/timeline/luna-24.jpg" width='240' alt="Luna 24" class="timeline-item-image">
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <time>9 August 1976</time>
                            <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-5">
                        <img src="/images/timeline/hiten.jpg" width='240' alt="Hiten" class="timeline-item-image">
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <time>24 January 1990</time>
                            <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                                <br/> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-6">
                        <img src="/images/timeline/artemis.jpg" width='240' alt="ARTEMIS" class="timeline-item-image">
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <time>Spring 2010</time>
                            <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
                                <br> Text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to order them - just use flex direction row with flex wrap, 50% width on desktop and 100% on mobile - http://jsfiddle.net/L2owhdau/2

Comment: ..also a **minimal** demo is preferred.

Comment: Thanks guys! I agree @Paulie_D - I tried to upload the code but it was too long for the box - would the site zipped up like this do? https://www.dropbox.com/s/igj9ie364quewmb/flex-wrap%20issue.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to set order, as mentioned in comments.

Just set correct `flex-basis` for mobile (`100%`) and desktop (`50%`):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.item {
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px dashed lightblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .item {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```